# ion-toggle : Reduce size of toggle button

Tags: ionic-framework, togglebutton

Is there any way to reduce the size of ion-toggle button.
The picture depicts my problem.
[image: Expection Vs. Current Implementation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are creating toggle button like this:

```
<label class="toggle">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <div class="track">
     <div class="handle"></div>
   </div>
</label>
```

Use `.toggle .track` class to adjust following css properties:

```
width: 51px;
height: 31px;
```

and then `.toggle .handle` to adjust following css properties:

```
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
top: 7px;
left: 7px;
```

You may also add your own class name to change appearance of specific toggle buttons.

In case you are using `ion-toggle` directive as in

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="airplaneMode" class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm">Airplane Mode</ion-toggle>
```

You can try to see if applying `class="toggle-small"` changes appearance as per your need. However, above class modifications can still be applied to this directive.

Answer (score 32):

try this

```
ion-toggle {
  zoom: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: it works, you dont have to add any css just mention this to style page and works like magic..thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you will need to customize three CSS definitions: .toggle-icon, .toggle-inner, and .toggle-checked .toggle-inner.

- .toggle-icon: width and height change the size of the toggle "track"
- .toggle-inner: width and height change the size of the toggle "button" that slides in the track
- .toggle-checked .toggle-inner.: transform: translate3d(27px, 0, 0) The first arg changes the position of the button when it is pressed

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to enlarge so to answer the OP you can simply use smaller values to get a minuscule toggle.

CSS zoom suggested above appears to be outdated 2017 post in my calendar is not that old.  Anyways, it does not take virtual units.

While I am constantly fighting all this non-sense of frameworks and CSS cryptic lingo I have been always trying to use virtual units even for font-size.  Because they are a percentage of the real-estate a platform presents, I feel they provide better results with a single specification, occasionally I specify separately for portrait and landscape.

So for the toggle I have derived the following gathering from all your inputs and other posts.  In order to have a decent appearance I tend to like things large but they still have to fit an iphone, android and my TV 1920 x 1000

I **personally** think it's totally stupid to keep speaking and specifying CSS with weird units like px, em, etc....

[image]

Here is the looks on an iphone 
[image]

Here is the looks on my large TV

[image]

As you can see I still have some more styling to do for the radio-buttons they are tiny on my 1920 x 1080 TV.  I will derive a style common for both that will work (unlike the Ionic default which DOES NOT, otherwise we won't be here, would we?).

Programmers should NOT have to do this, It's a shame frameworks make it such a pain, when they claim to do the opposite (enabling you to publish on various platform).

Thanks for @amuramoto for the translate, I am just hacking my way thru the dev tools figuring out all this terrible mess.

Here is what I cooked up for the radio-buttons I don't know why I am having to use 5.5vmin to center the .radio-icon ?? it's not looking great on the iphone yet.  Perhaps someone can improve on this?

[image]

here are the radio-buttons on the 1920 x 1080 resolution

[image]